# Use Nps Server as MFA middleware

Tags: nps, azure-mfa

My company uses NPS Server and Microsoft Authenticator app to facilitate two factor authentication for RDP connections. We are Windows Server 2016 and Azure Active Directory.

Would it be possible to re-use this NPS infrastructure to authenticate requests to a web application directly without being in an RDP session?

If so, do you know an example implementation for it.